# watch equivalent in zsh

Tags: zsh

In `bash`, `watch` (e.g. `watch -n 5 ls -l`) could be used to repeat the command at fixed intervals.

This command seem to be missing on zsh.  Is there an equivalent?

Comment: `watch` is not a builtin. It is an external command.

Comment: Something mangle your $PATH?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

`watch` is not an internal command:

```
$ type watch
/usr/bin/watch
```

so make sure it installed on the system where you are running `zsh`.

Comment: That was it. I'm running Mac OSX, which didn't come with it. So installed via homebrew: `brew install watch`. http://stackoverflow.com/a/23370705/1175956

Answer (score 2):

I just improvised watch with: `clear; while ls -lah; do sleep 2; clear; done`

Interesting idea. I could write a function around that... Right, put this in your .zshrc

```bsh
watch () {
    IN=2
    case $1 in
        -n)
            IN=$2
            shift 2
            ;;
    esac
    printf '\033c' # clear
    CM="$*"
    LEFT="$(printf 'Every %.1f: %s' $IN $CM)"
    ((PAD = COLUMNS - ${#LEFT}))
    while :
    do
        DT=$(date)
        printf "$LEFT%${PAD}s\n" "$HOST $(date)"
        eval "$CM"
        sleep $IN
        printf '\033c'
    done
}
```

Comment: Why reinvent the wheel? Also, how about the other options like `-d`, `-g`, etc?

Comment: Because not everybody uses Linux where it is installed by default. On OSX and the BSDs you'd have to install a package. Also, my aliases won't work in the normal watch. I don't care about the other features. If you do, feel free to add them. Also, you learn coding by doing it.